# Set height on div with CSS3 transform (rotate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

**Goal**

I'm working on a collapsible sidebar using jQuery for animation. I would like to have vertical text on the sidebar that acts as a label and can swap on the animateOut/animateIn effect.

Normally I would use an image of the text that I've simply swapped vertically, and switch it out on animation, but with CSS3 transforms I'd like to get it to work instead.

**Problem**

The problem I'm facing is that setting the height on my rotated container makes it expand horizontally (as it's rotated 90deg) so that doesn't work. I then tried to set the width (hoping it would expand vertically, acting as height), but that has an odd effect of causing the width of my parent container to expand as well.

**Fix?**

*How can I set the height on a rotated (transformed) element without affecting the width of the parent container? So far I have been unable to do this.*

**Live Example**

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates my problem: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mnRF/2/)

The `collapse-pane` class is what I have rotated and contains the span I have my text inside. You'll notice it has a width set, that widens the border, but also affects the parent container.

The code:

CSS:

```
.right-panel{
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#efefef;
}
.collapse-pane{
    margin-top:50px;
    width:30px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    cursor:pointer;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);   
}
.collapse-pane span{
    padding:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="right-panel">
    <div class="collapse-pane">
        <span class="expand">Expand</span>
    </div>
    <div style="width:0;" class="panel-body">
        <div style="display:none;" class="panel-body-inner">
            adsfasdfasdf
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an image also showing the problem, so you don't have to view the Fiddle.

[image: Weird div spacing]

**Update**

I've made the problem statement a little clearer, as my original post was confusing the issues.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @malcoda Why are you transforming the container? Just transform the contents within the container.

Comment: Updated to include code.

Comment: @Malcoda - give your `collapse-pane` `display: inline-block;`. you do not need any JS code what-so-ever to do any of the things you are doing here btw.

Comment: The JS isn't really relevant to the problem. How can I add height to a rotated container without effecting the parent container? setting the display to inline block didn't seem to help.

Comment: @malcoda You still have the rotation on the collapse-pane class and not the actual span.

Comment: @Malcoda although your question documents the issue well, I am having trouble understanding the desired layout. take a look at this fiddle and tell me this is what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8mnRF/17/

Comment: @web-tiki I was curious as to why setting the width of the inner span was affecting it's parent width (since it's rotated. And how to set the width of the span without affecting the containing div. Your solution would work, but it's not exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Malcoda tell me what is wrong with my fiddle and I'll improve it and make a proper answer.

Comment: @web-tiki I would like the div containing the span ("Expand") to be 100% of the height of the screen and for it to be unaffected by the changes to the span width. As I think at this point I'm looking at nuances, if you make what you have into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the rotated divs size expand it's parent size, you need to take it out of the flow. You may use absolute positioning for this.

The following demo uses this technique and also positions the "expand" element by setting a transform orign and top/right values.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/8mnRF/17/)**

*CSS :*

```
.right-panel {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#efefef;
}
.collapse-pane {
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #999;
    cursor:pointer;
    top:20%;
    right:100%;
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
.collapse-pane span {
    padding:5px;
}
```

*jQuery :*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var height = $(".right-panel").height();
    $('.collapse-pane').click(function () {
        if ($(".collapse-pane span").html() == "Expand") {
            $(".panel-body").animate({
                width: 200
            }, 400);
            $(".panel-body-inner").fadeIn(500);
            $(".collapse-pane span").html("Collapse");
        } else {
            $(".panel-body").animate({
                width: 00
            }, 400);
            $(".panel-body-inner").fadeOut(300);
            $(".collapse-pane span").html("Expand");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for bearing with my lengthy post. Good answer!